# Similarity measure between two tetrahedron

Tags: euclidean-geometry, lie-algebras, error-function

Given that there are two tetrahedrons $\mathbf{T} = \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{A} & \mathbf{B} & \mathbf{C} & \mathbf{D} \end{bmatrix}^{\top}$ and $\mathbf{T}^{\ast} = \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{A}^{\ast} & \mathbf{B}^{\ast} & \mathbf{C}^{\ast} & \mathbf{D}^{\ast} \end{bmatrix}^{\top}$, where $\mathbf{T}$ is the tetrahedron and $\mathbf{T}^{\ast}$ is a deformed tetrahedron with a one-to-one correspondence between the vertices of $\mathbf{T}$ and $\mathbf{T}^{\ast}$, I would like to find a way of measuring the similarity between the two tetrahedrons. $\mathbf{A}, \mathbf{B}, \mathbf{C}, \mathbf{D}, \mathbf{A}^{\ast}, \mathbf{B}^{\ast}, \mathbf{C}^{\ast}, \mathbf{D}^{\ast} $ are 3D cartesian coordinates.

[image: Seeking similarity measure between two tetrahedron]

An obvious choice of similarity between the two tetrahedrons is the Eucledian distance $\| \mathbf{T} - \mathbf{T}^{\ast}\|$. However, it is evident that the Eucledian distance is non-unique, i.e., multiple deformed configurations can result in the same distance.

The final objective is to minimize the distance between the two deformed configurations (via certain controlled deformations applied on $\mathbf{T}$) and ideally, the similarity function should possess the following properties:

1. Should be continuously differentiable
2. Should result in non-unique similarity measures
3. Should preferably be able to distinguish between deformation and translation without resorting to centroid matching etc. (*this 3rd property is optional... good to have, but not strictly necessary*)

Perhaps something similar to this Lie algebraic approach [[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSGZK.png)] could be useful in this case. But while [[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSGZK.png)] does this for triangles, I am looking for something on tetrahedrons.

Could you please share your opinion on this.

*Thanks in advance to the entire community..... folks at math.stackexchange are awesome.*

---

[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSGZK.png)] Freifeld, Oren, and Michael J. Black. "Lie bodies: A manifold representation of 3D human shape." European Conference on Computer Vision. Springer, Berlin, Heidelberg, 2012.